# Set react-scripts test environment file

Tags: reactjs, testing, environment-variables, create-react-app, react-scripts

We're using `react-scripts` to run our tests, via the command `react-scripts test`. Locally we have our own test environments, and use the `.env.test` file as the environment file (it uses this automatically).

However, in our CircleCI environment we want to run the tests using the development environment, i.e. using `.env.development`. I can't figure out how to tell `react-scripts` to use the dev env file, I've tried setting various values before running the command like `REACT_APP_ENV` and `NODE_ENV`. I've tried using the [env-cmd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd) module to specify it to use the dev env file (e.g. `env-cmd .env.development react-scripts test`), but it STILL uses the test one.

I know in the CircleCI test command I could just overwrite the test env file with the dev one (something like `cp -rf .env.development .env.test && react-scripts test`), but I was wondering if there was a cleaner way of doing it (since if I did it that way, if we wanted to test using dev environment locally, it'd overwrite our personal `.env.test` files)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing you need to do is to modify the `react-scripts test` command by adding the following:

```
--env=jsdom
```

So the end result would be

```
// package.json
{
    "scripts": {
        ...
        "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom"
        ...
    }
}
```

https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/environments-in-create-react-app.html